# jQuery Datepicker show one format, send another

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, datepicker

So I'm using the jQuery Datepicker script on a few of my textboxes.

```
$(function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "M d, yy" }).val()
});
```

I would like to show the `date` in the `textbox` as for example, `Feb 4, 2017` 
but then send it as `yy-mm-dd` so that it matches the dates in the `database` and give me a result.

Is this possible? I'm using razor, and it's not a MVC project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use MomentJS to parse the value into a Moment object and then format it to the way you need it.

```
moment('2-4-17').format('YY-MM-DD');
```

[MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/)

Step 1: Insert script before end of `</body>` tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Step 2:

```
$(function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "M d, yy" }).val()
});
```

to

```
$(function() {

    // Get Date from datepicker
    var date = $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "M d, yy" }).val();

    // Use the date to create a Moment Object and format it so that it can be 
    // used within the databse
    var databaseDate = moment(date).format('YY-MM-DD');

    // Use your correctly formatted date however you want, in this example
    // we are just console logging it to take a look if it's correctly parsed.
    console.log(databaseDate);

});
```

Comment: this looks really good, and smart, but I'm a complete noob at javascript so I wouldn't know how to use this line of code, do I just put it inside my current script?

Comment: Ahh no problem. Check my post for a code snippet. Can you post a mock value of `$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "M d, yy" }).val()`?

Comment: I had to fix moment(date).format('YY-MM-DD'); in the second step as I put a capital M and that is wrong, just making sure you know I've edited it :-)

Comment: did actually work both ways, was quick to try it haha, changed it anyway, but it's working and I'm super happy, big thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing new datepicker that time write below code which display Feb 4, 2017 this format

```
$(function() {
   $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "M d, yy" })
});
```

While retrieving value from textbox and sending it to database there use below code

```
var senddt=$('.datepicker').datepicker("option","dateFormat","yy-mm-dd").val();
```